# How can I fix Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN after installing certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

My web server's FQDN is foo.bar.com

It is aliased and most commonly accessed at baz.bar.com

I had a SSL certificate generated by our netsec guys and I installed it to the server and enabled the site. Now I am receiving Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN because the certificate is only for foo.bar.com, not baz.bar.com

How can I get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname in the URL you use to access a site must match a subject of the certificate. This means if you want to access the site as bot `baz.bar.com` and `foo.bar.com` you either need a certificate which contains both or need two certificates and serve the certificate based on the request name. In the last case the client must support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) if both names point to the same IP address.